# Use PEM certificate format in Wildfly application server

Tags: wildfly

In a Wildfly 28 installation, I'm currently using a JKS keystore for the certificates.
However, I'd prefer to move to PEM files directly, which are more common, so I can save some conversion steps. So I have two files, a `server.crt` (the certificate) and a `server.key` (the private key)

Does Wildfly configuration support these? If yes, what do I have to put in the `standalone.xml`?